# Jquery - Create an array from a delimited string and then evaluate its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i've this problem i'm not really able to solve.

i have this string "B01, B20, B03, "

i would like to create a jQuery array off this string using the "," as delimiter
then remove the last element ( that would be blank ) and then for each value of the
array make an alert.

Something like...

```
 var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ";

    var theArray = (theString, ',');

    theArray = remove_last_element;  (??)

    $('theArray').each(function() {

      alert(theArray[?].value); 

    });
```

Any hint ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ";

$.each(theString.split(",").slice(0,-1), function(index, item) {
    alert(item); 
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Why are you putting the array in a jQuery object?

Comment: @Guffa I assumed he wanted a jQuery object by the wording in his question.

Comment: Wonderful, i ended up choosing this way because is really compact and nice ! Thank you very much for your help !. @Guffa, i'm a total newbie i'm still learning :)

Answer (score 12):

There is no such thing as a "jQuery array". You use a Javascript array.

You can't just turn a string into an array because it contains comma separated values. You have to use something to parse the string, which would be the `split` method in this case:

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ";
var theArray = theString.split(", ");
```

This produces an array with four items, as there is a trailing separator, so you can check for that and remove it:

```
if (theArray.length > 0 && theArray[theArray.length - 1].length == 0) {
  theArray.pop();
}
```

Then you can either use plain Javascript or a jQuery method to loop the array. The plain Javascript looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
  alert(theArray[i]);
}
```

Using a jQuery method looks like this:

```
$.each(theArray, function(index, item) {
  alert(item);
});
```

You can also skip the step of removing the item, and just check for empty items in the loop:

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ";
var theArray = theString.split(", ");
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
  if (theArray[i].length > 0) {
    alert(theArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this.  Use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string, then loop through it with [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ",
    bits = theString.split(', ').slice(0, -1); // split the string and remove the last one

for (var i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
    alert(bits[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm a total newbie :) i thought i needed to use jQuery because all other script use it. Anyway you very much for taking time to helping me out

Answer (score 1):

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ",
    theArray = theString.split(', ');

theArray.pop();
$(theArray).each(function() {
  alert(this); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to helping me out

Answer (score 0):

The only jquery I used below was to "trim" the value to see if it was empty.  Otherwise, I used split and splice (plain ol' javascript).

```
var theString = "B01, B20, B03, ";
var theArray = theString.split(',');
for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++) {
  // check if any array element is empty, if so, take it out of the array
  if ($.trim(theArray[i]) == "")
    theArray.splice(i, 1); // remove element since it's blank
}

// now you can iterate over the "real" values of the array
$.each(theArray, function(i, value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "B01, B20, B03, ";

$.each(str.split(','), function(i, val) {
  val = $.trim(val);
  alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cleanString = function(str) {
    return $.grep(str.split(','), function(elem) {
        return ($.trim(elem) !== '')
    });
}
```

This function will return an array with all split by comma with all the blanks removed. Check out [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Usage

```
cleanString("B01, B20, B03, ");
```

Alerting the array should be simple enough. It's just a matter of iterating over the returned array.

```
  var arr = cleanString("B01, B20, B03, ");
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) { 
      alert(value); 
  });
```